# El contenedor de Docker Compose en Nginx no enruta correctamente

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, docker-compose

Estoy iniciándome en esto de los contenedores de *Docker* y siguiendo un tutorial, he creado un archivo **docker-compose.yml** para tener un servidor de aplicaciones web basado en Nginx, *PHP7-fpm*, *MySQL* y *Laravel* (todos en sus últimas versiones).

Funciona pero no como debería ya que cuando accedo a la *IP* del servicio me muestra la página de *Nginx* en vez de la de *Laravel*.

Estoy usando *Ubuntu 16.04.2 64bits* y *Docker Compose*. El código del archivo *YML* es el siguiente:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '2'

services:
# The Application
app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"

# The Web Server
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  # The Database
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_USER=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

El archivo de configuración de web es este:

```
FROM nginx:latest
ADD vhost.conf /nginx/conf.d/default.conf
# Añadido por mi a ver si enruta bien
WORKDIR /var/www
```

El **vhost.conf** es este:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcig_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_parm SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

El de aplicación es el siguiente:

```
FROM php:7.0.15-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
mysql-client libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
&& pecl install imagick \
&& docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
&& docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que veo es que en tu **vhost.conf** estas indicando que el parametro **fastcgi_pass** apunte a **app:9000**, que imagino sera el contenedor de PHP-FPM.

Bueno esto no va a funcionar nunca, ya que no se "ven" entre si los contenedores a menos que los linkees o los pongas dentro de una misma **network**.

Agrega al final de tu **docker-compose** esto:

```
networks:
  appnet:
   driver: bridge
```

Y luego en cada servicio le agregas:

```
networks:
  - appnet
```

Y con eso estas indicando que cada servicio pertenece a la misma "red".
De esa manera el contenedor de **nginx** va a saber quien es **app**.

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Pues sin cambiar nada funcionó, fue cuestión de reiniciar la maquina.